# How to hide/show a div when a certain div is in view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, fadein, fadeout

I need to make a div fade out if another div is showing on screen. I've been told that I need to use Javascript to do this, as well as making it load automatically.

Does anyone know a solution?

I've googled around, and I've tried to edit the following, but I'm having no luck implementing it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onLoad(function () {
        if ($('.section5').is(":visible")) {
            $(".arrow").fadeOut(fast);
        } else if ($('.section5').is(":hidden")) {
            $('.arrow').fadeIn(fast);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are looking for the solution to make the div show/hide when you scroll down or up the page, and to make it visible when you scroll the page and the other div is not on the page after scroll , here is what you should do:

assume that the div that should be visible on the form while scrolling is like that:

```
<div id='div1'></div>
```

and the div that should hide and show accordingly is like that:

```
 <div id='div2'></div>
```

here is the script you show use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        AdjustDiv();

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            AdjustDiv();
        })
    });

    function AdjustDiv() {
        var windowheight = window.innerHeight;
        var div1height = $('#div1').height();


        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var div1top = $('#div1').offset().top;


        var window_bottom = scroll_top + windowheight;
        var div1_bottom = div1top + div1height;


        if
        (
            (
                (scroll_top >= div1top)
                &&
                (scroll_top < div1_bottom)
            )
            ||
            (
                (scroll_top <= div1top)
                &&
                (window_bottom >= div1_bottom)
            )
            ||
            (
                (scroll_top <= div1top)
                &&
                (window_bottom > div1top)
            )
        ) {
            $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
        }
        else {
            $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    }
</script>
```

just for demo i turn the background red if the div1 is not visible and green if visible

and here is the complete example, please try:

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id='div0' style='border: solid 1px black;'>
                <p>
                    aadsa dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas da2121212121s dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
            </div>
            <div id='div1' style='border: solid 1px black;'>
                <h1>
                    DIV 1</h1>
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
            </div>
            <div id='div3' style='border: solid 1px black;'>
                <p>
                    aadsa dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas da2121212121s dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
            </div>
            <div id='div4' style='border: solid 1px black;'>
                <p>
                    aadsa dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas da2121212121s dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
                <br />
                <p>
                    tdasd dasdas das dasdas das das</p>
            </div>
            <div id='div2' style='border: solid 1px black;'>
                div 2<br />
                div 2<br />
                div 2<br />
                div 2<br />
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    AdjustDiv();

                    $(window).scroll(function () {
                        AdjustDiv();
                    })
                });

                function AdjustDiv() {
                    var windowheight = window.innerHeight;
                    var div1height = $('#div1').height();


                    var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
                    var div1top = $('#div1').offset().top;


                    var window_bottom = scroll_top + windowheight;
                    var div1_bottom = div1top + div1height;


                    if
                    (
                        (
                            (scroll_top >= div1top)
                            &&
                            (scroll_top < div1_bottom)
                        )
                        ||
                        (
                            (scroll_top <= div1top)
                            &&
                            (window_bottom >= div1_bottom)
                        )
                        ||
                        (
                            (scroll_top <= div1top)
                            &&
                            (window_bottom > div1top)
                        )
                    ) {
                        $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Kariem. I still can't get it working. I think it's to do with the window DIV taking up the space of the entire window.What does `var windowheight = window.innerHeight;
var div1height = $('#div1').height();` do?

Comment: var windowheight = window.innerHeight; gets the height of the visible area of the page

and
var div1height = $('#div1').height(); gets the height of the div which we check if it's within the visible area or not,


post the code that you use and i can edit it so you get it working

Answer (score 2):

`window.onLoad` is not a `function` use `$(function(){...})`

And `fast` is a `string` not `variable` try this,

```
$(function () {
    if ($('.section5').is(":visible")) {
        $(".arrow").fadeOut('fast');
    } else if ($('.section5').is(":hidden")) {
        $('.arrow').fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried using that, but nothing changed. Any idea on what it could be?